# HTTP on mobile devices based on different handset

Tags: http, mobile-phones

I have little information about different handset I do not know exactly what can be mobile handset?can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at the user agent header in the http request.

http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into the User-Agent strings, a list of which can be found here: http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html .

Keep in mind that it's not 100% reliable, because many mobile browsers pretend to be desktop browsers (I know Skyfire encourages this just in case there are more videos in the desktop version).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what's serving your pages up.  The general method this is accomplished is by looking at the browser's user agent and then directing them to the appropriate page/template.

Comment: I have little information about different handset I do not know exactly what can be mobile handset?can you help me?